# How to specify select placeholder?

Tags: laravel-backpack

In one of my crud controllers I tried to do the following to add placeholder (disabled selected option) for select

```
        $this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name' => 'measurement_id',
            'label' => 'Measurement',
            'type' => 'select',
            'entity' => 'measurement',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => Measurement::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'placeholder' => 'My placeholder',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

But it doesn't work. It generates the following html.

```
<select name="measurement_id" placeholder="My placeholder">
   <option value="1">option1</option>
   <option value="2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way it generates proper html?

```
<select name="measurement_id">
   <option disabled selected>My placeholder</option>
   <option value="1">option1</option>
   <option value="2">option2</option>
</select>
```